# How to avoid damaging of a paragraph with `lettrine` and `varwidth` while using `chickenize`?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, lettrine, varwidth

Trying to put automatically one symbol-words (as shown by arrows on the screenshot 1) from the end of the line into the beginning of the new line in scrbook (according to the topical typography rules) across all document.

[image]

I've put

```
    \usepackage{chickenize}
    \suppressonecharbreak
```

It works fine for onesymbol-words, but...

```
\documentclass[a5paper,DIV=calc,twoside=true,fontsize=14pt,]{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{Red}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{Red}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{Red}}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles % remove the default elements of headings and plain pages
\ohead{\pagemark}      % page number right aligned in the head of headings pages only

    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\suppressonecharbreak

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{auxhook}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\emergencystretch=10pt
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000

%==============Asterix footnote==================
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\setfnsymbol{wiley}

%===============Asterix footnote counter reset===========

   \makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}
\makeatother

%-------------Sections format-----------
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}

    \RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\Large,
    afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=14pt,% skip before section heading
  afterskip=14pt,% skip after section heading
  runin=false% freestanding heading
]{section}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\normalsize,
   afterindent=false,
 beforeskip=14pt,% skip before section heading
 afterskip=14pt,% skip after section heading
 runin=false% freestanding heading
]{subsection}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
 \color{Red}\Ifstr{#1}{section}
   {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
   {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
 \color{Red}\Ifstr{#1}{subsection}
   {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
   {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other      section levels
}

%----------SNIPSETS------
\newcommand{\Anagnosma}[1]{%
\begin{center}
   \textbf{\color{Red}\normalsize #1} \end{center}}

\newcommand{\AnagnosmaTwo}[1]
{\begin{center}
   {#1} \end{center}}

\newcommand{\redc}[1]{%
\textcolor{Red}{#1}}

\newcommand{\redcbt}[1] 
{\textbf{\textcolor{Red}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\Bukva}[1]
    {\lettrine[grid=true, lines=2]{\textbf{\textcolor{Red}{#1}}}}

%=======Letrine with Gospel in two line=======
\usepackage{varwidth}
\makeatletter
\define@key{L}{prelude}{%
  \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{%
    \quad
    \makebox[\L@prewidth][c]{%
      \begin{varwidth}[t]{12em}
      \em\footnotesize\color{Red} #1
      \end{varwidth}%
    }\quad
  }%
}
\define@key{L}{prewidth}{\renewcommand*{\L@prewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\L@prewidth}{\width}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.15}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Red}{}}
\makeatother
%==========================================
 
\usepackage{xparse}
 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{prayer}{O{}mm}{%
  \lettrine[#1]{#2}{#3}%
}%==================

\begin{document}
    \noindent
        \pagebreak
\section{БОЖЕСТВЕННЕ ТА СВЯТЕ\\ЄВАНГЕЛІЄ
ВІД ІОАНА}
    
\subsection{У середу Світлого Тижня}

    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 1:35-51]{О}{дного разу} стояв Іоан та з учнів його двоє.
 І, поглянувши на Ісуса, Який ішов, говорить: «Ось Агнець Божий».
І почули два учні, як Він говорив, і пішли за Ісусом.
Ісус же, обернувшись і побачивши, що вони йдуть за Ним, говорить їм: «Чого шукаєте?» Вони ж сказали Йому: «Раббі (що в перекладі означає: “учителю”), де живеш?»
Говорить їм: «Приходьте й подивіться». Вони прийшли й побачили, де Він живе; і в Нього пробули день той. Було близько десятої години.
Один із тих двох, які почули від Іоана про Ісуса і пішли за Ним, був Андрій, брат Симона Петра.
Він перший знаходить брата свого Симона й каже йому: «Ми знайшли Месію (що перекладається: “Христос”)!»
І привів його до Ісуса. Поглянувши на нього, Ісус сказав: «Ти — Симон, син Іони, ти наречешся Кифа (що перекладається: “Петро”)».
Наступного дня захотів Ісус вийти в Галілею, і знаходить Филипа і каже йому: «Йди за Мною».
Був же Филип з Віфсаїди, з міста Андрія й Петра.
Знаходить Филип Нафанаїла і каже йому: «Того, про Якого написав Мойсей у Законі і пророки, ми знайшли — Ісуса, сина Йосифа, з Назарета!»
І сказав йому Нафанаїл: «Хіба з Назарета може щось добре бути?» Говорить йому Филип: «Приходь і подивись».
Побачив Ісус Нафанаїла, який ішов до Нього, і говорить про нього: «Ось воістину ізраїльтянин, в якому нема підступності».
Говорить Йому Нафанаїл: «Звідки Ти мене знаєш?» Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Перш ніж тебе Филип покликав, коли ти був під смоківницею, Я побачив тебе».
Відповів Нафанаїл і каже Йому: «Раббі, Ти — Син Божий, Ти — Цар Ізраїля!»
Відповів Ісус і сказав йому: «Ти віриш, тому що Я сказав тобі: Я побачив тебе під смоківницею? Більше цього побачиш».
І говорить йому: «Амінь, амінь кажу вам: віднині побачите небо відкрите і Ангелів Божих, які піднімаються і спускаються до Сина Людського».

\end{prayer}
\end{document}
```

It's damaging the beginning of paragraph with `lettrine` and `varwidth` (screenshot 2). **How to avoid this damaging?**

[image]

Comment: unrelated but remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` all it does is give a warning that it should not be used

Comment: thanks. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding braces to the `varwidth` content solves the issue.

```
\define@key{L}{prelude}{%
    \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{%
        \quad
        \makebox[\L@prewidth][c]{%
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{12em}
                    {\em\footnotesize\textcolor{Red}{#1}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \end{varwidth}%
        }
    \quad
    }%
}
```

(using `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` )

[image: a]

A similar result can be obtained with a simpler code

```
\define@key{L}{prelude}{%
    \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{%
        \quad\raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}{\em\footnotesize\textcolor{Red}{#1}}\quad%
    }%
}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question: two (long) lines in the prelude

```
\define@key{L}{prelude}{%
    \renewcommand*{\L@ante}{%
        \quad
        \raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}{%
        \begin{varwidth}[c]{12em}
                {\em\footnotesize\textcolor{Red}{#1}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{varwidth}}%
    \quad
    }%
}
```

[image: c]

Using

```
    \begin{prayer}[prelude=Іоана 1:35-51 / 1:35-51 \\ Іоана 1:35-51 / 1:35-51]{О}{дного разу} стояв Іоан та з учнів його двоє.
```

Comment: Extent! Thank you!For the second point of your answer: very elegant solution, but it doesn't work when small text in `varwidth` is long and have to break in two or even three lines with \\. Entire text stays in one line and give almost the same effect for the paragraph like it was before adding braces to the `varwidth`

Comment: @filokalos Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I'm very appreciate  you. Could you be so kind and help with break lines in `varwidth` so I could use your solution?

Comment: @filokalos Please the updated answer. More than two lines requires to have more lines hanging from the lettrine.

Comment: Awesome! It's really greate! Thanks! LuaLatex produces pdf-file correct, but I think I've missed something or written something wrong, because it shows me tis messages "Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line". Is it something serious or not? If not, so your solution is really fantastic! Thank you once more!

Comment: @filokalos Use  `{\em\footnotesize\textcolor{Red}{#1}}` to suppress the warning.